# CLR20r3 - Winform.exe - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, azure

I have a .Net Winforms application, but when my Winform has finished all the tasks, it will appear an issue of CLR20r3, which can stop my Winform application because of this error.

I'm running my Winform within the Azure Visual Machine, which has the .Net framework 4.0 or above, I have checked it.

Is there any idea about how to solve this problem?

Comment: Thanks Marc_s for helping me modifying my words

Answer (score 1):

I have the same kind of problem.

[Click here for the Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxD0l.png)

I install DtNetFrameWork v4.6 whatsoever..but not solving the problem.

So lastly I installed Visual Studio 2015 (I used it for compiling) on the machine where I want to run my program....howwww. It works that way....

I guess there was a Symbol loading problem, but it's not.

Try installing DotNetFrameWork update!